# Java confusion about initializing the swing components

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm confused about initializing the Swing components like JTextField and other components. Calling from the DoSth class, the getTxtUser returns null pointer exception whereas if getTxtUser() from its own class returns the value correctly.Please help me.Thanks 
Code:

```
public class GUI{
    private JLabel lblUname;
    private JTextField txtUname;


    public void showGUI(){
       lblUname = new JLabel("Username");
       txtUname = new JTextField(20);
       ....................

    }

    public String getTxtUser(){
    return this.txtUname.getText();
    }

 }

 public class DoSth(){
     .............. 
     GUI g = new GUI();
     String user = g.getTxtUser(); //null pointer Exception even if it has some value
     ...............
 }
```

Comment: you never called "showGUI()"

Comment: Shouldn't some of the `showGUI()` code be in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks guys but managing the code is really being very hard for me.

Answer (score 2):

`txtUname` is not initialized in a constructor and hence calling the method `getTxtUser` form `DoSth` class results in NPE. Either move your GUI components initialization in a constructor or call  `showGUI` method to initialize them.

```
GUI g = new GUI();
g.showGUI();
String user = g.getTxtUser();
```